# Node theme template override isn't working

Tags: theming

I'm using the paid theme md-alpine and I added a content type called webinars, and a node template for webinars node--webinars.tpl.php

The only thing I put in the page is  and I only get an HTML page with no CSS.  Am I supposed to add a call to the node--webinars.tpl.php page somewhere?

EDIT: I changed dpm to print_r and the rest of the theme printed.  Put it back to dpm and it doesn't load.

[image]

This is the raw output of the page:

```
    <div id="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <i class="icon fontello icon-menu icon-2x"></i>
            </button>
            <a id="brand" class="navbar-brand" href="http://lcl.alpine.test"> <img src="http://lcl.alpine.test/sites/all/themes/md_alpine/img/logo.png" alt=""> </a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="menu nav navbar-nav navbar-right"><li><a class="int-collapse-menu" href="http://lcl.alpine.test/#home">Home</a></li><li><a class="int-collapse-menu" href="http://lcl.alpine.test/#about">About</a></li><li><a class="int-collapse-menu" href="http://lcl.alpine.test/#portfolio">Gallery</a></li><li><a class="int-collapse-menu" href="http://lcl.alpine.test/#team">Staff</a></li><li><a class="int-collapse-menu" href="http://lcl.alpine.test/#client">Testimonials</a></li><li><a class="int-collapse-menu" href="http://lcl.alpine.test/#pricing">Donations</a></li><li><a class="int-collapse-menu" href="http://lcl.alpine.test/#blog">Blog</a></li><li><a class="int-collapse-menu" href="http://lcl.alpine.test/#contact">Contact</a></li><li class="last leaf"><a href="/members" title="Member&#039;s Area">Members</a></li>
</ul>        </div>
    </div>
</div><section class="section-content blog-content">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Section title -->
                <div class="section-title text-center">
            <div>

                <span class="line big"></span>
                <span>Posted by <a href="http://lcl.alpine.test/user/1">admin</a></span>
                <span class="line big"></span>

            </div>
            <h1>Test</h1>
            <div>
                <span class="line"></span>
                <span><i class="fontello icon-calendar"></i>21 June 2014</span>
                <span class="line"></span>
            </div>
            <p class="lead">
                            </p>
        </div>
                <!-- Section title -->
        <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                                <div class="tabs"><h2 class="element-invisible">Primary tabs</h2><ul class="tabs primary"><li class="active"><a href="/webinars/test" class="active">View<span class="element-invisible">(active tab)</span></a></li>
<li><a href="/node/39/edit">Edit</a></li>
</ul></div>
```

Comment: " I changed dpm to print_r and the rest of the theme printed" - where, and why? - neither of these functions have anything to do with the standard output and shouldn't affect it? can you post your node--webinars.tpl.php if it isn't too big.

Comment: node--webinars.tpl.php - it's called automatically, looks like you broke something, so page.tpl.php or html.tpl.php doesn't fired. Need to more investigate, did you add code to template.php?

Answer (score 0):

Devel got disabled somehow breaking the page when calling dpm.
Re-enabling fixed all.